# Computation of the derivative of a matrix-valued function

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, matrix-calculus, frechet-derivative

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$, $f:\mathbb{R}^a \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{b \times c}$ be Frèchet-differentiable with  Frèchet-derivative $Df$ and let $y,x \in \mathbb{R}^a$.

Is there a way to compute $(Df)(x)y$?

I know that $Df$ is the Jacobi matrix in case of b=a,c=1, but I have no idea how to compute $(Df)(x)y$ for general $a,b$. I think that $(Df)(x)y \in \mathbb{R}^{b \times c}$ holds.

I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ f(x_0) 
= \Big(
\left.\frac{∂f_{}}{∂x_{}}\right\vert_{x=x_0}
\Big)_{, }
\qquad 
f(x_0)(y)
= \Big(\sum_{} f(x_0)_{, } y_{}\Big)_{}
$$

For multi-indices $$ and $$.

Comment: The key is that the jacobian has rows for each function element and columns for each coordinate to create a matrix, and then it becomes a matrix/vector product. Also isn't $\nabla \boldsymbol{f}$ also the same as the Jacobian?